# Is the code for every system call loaded into address of each process?

Tags: operating-system

I have read a few articles and watched some videos on youtube about system calls. What I've noticed is that a system call doesn't generally require a context switch to another process; instead, it is processed in the context of whichever process invoked it. I read that kernel code for the system calls and table for system calls are placed inside the address space of each process. In the address space of a process, kernel code lies at the top, and below that lies the call stack. But that code is only accessible in system calls. When a particular system call starts execution, its stack frame is also placed in the call stack of the process.

So my question is, when and how do all of these happen- the placement of kernel code for system calls and table for system call?

Comment: 1. There might be differences between different OSes. 2. A process operates in the context of virtual memory, so the kernel code (system calls) is not copied to the process memory, but some memory addresses in the process space are mapped to the kernel page frames.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But in the process memory (its virtual address space), there should be some information so that it can be mapped to actual physical memory for accessing the system call code. right? When is that job done? I am sorry I have not read much about paging in detail.

Comment: When a process is created the kernel sets up a page table for the process that contains references to physical memory frames. This table is not accessible to the process. From the process point of view it is the only entity residing in memory - it can only see its own data structures, although some page table entries may point to memory frames accessible to other processes and thus some memory can be shared. System call provided by prog lang is only a wrapper that makes preparations for execution of a proper system call routine by copying data into CPU registries and switching to kernel mode.

Comment: @marzelin Thank you so much for your time. I realized that if I want to learn O.S and its operation in an easier way, I have to learn the virtual addressing scheme. I read the whole virtual memory chapter. Now with your answer, everything just comes into their place clearly. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: One last question. So during the dynamic allocation of memory for the process, the os has to allocate a page frame to the process and the page table has to be updated accordingly by the os. right?

Comment: if a process wants to access an address on a page that hasn't been set up yet, a page fault is raised at which point the kernel steps up and prepares the page frame for the process.

Comment: Oh. so if I call malloc function, it invokes syscall brk, srk. It returns a virtual address or a page. Then when I want to write something to that address page fault will occur. Then kernel allocates a page frame for the process. Is this correct? So the page table for that process keeps updating.

Comment: something like that; the bottom line is that modern CPUs are equipped with MMU and OSes use page-based techniques to manage memory. Page frames are added/swapped/removed dynamically as needed to optimize memory usage.

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

The most common scenario is that that the CPU supports some kind of privilege level/s; the OS maps its code and data into every virtual address space as "requires highest privilege level to access" (in an area called "kernel space"), and normal processes are left using "lowest privilege level" so that if they try to access anything in the kernel the CPU refuses to allow it.

However; the CPU also provides various special control transfers that the OS can configure for things like IRQs and system calls.

Typically, for system calls, a program might call something like "`write()`" which will call a normal function in a (dynamically linked/shared) library (causing "write()" to be added to the call stack because it's just a normal function and not a system call itself). Inside the library, there'll be code to shuffle values around and prepare for a radically different calling convention, that uses some kind of special instruction (`int 0x80` or `syscall` or `sysenter` or ...) designed to change the CPU's privilege level and transfer control to the kernel's system call handler. This special control transfer won't show up on the call stack (mostly because the CPU switches to a completely different stack all-together as part of that special instruction).

Once the kernel's system call handler is reached; it will probably (if kernel isn't written in assembly) shift more stuff around in registers to match normal calling conventions compilers use, and use a "function number' parameter to find/call the intended function (typically using an array of function pointers, with an "is the function number within a sane range" check to avoid "index out of bounds" problems).

*Note: This is just the most common scenario (and very normal for Windows, OSX, Linux, etc); but different CPUs and different operating systems are different, and some times behavior is different for the same hardware/same OS. For one example, if an OS is running with "Meltdown vulnerability work-arounds" enabled it may do a virtual address space switch early in it's system call handler.*

> So my question is, when and how do all of these happen- the placement of kernel code for system calls and table for system call?

Most of this is set up during kernel initialization (during boot, likely before the first normal process is started); and once set up it's merely perpetuated (e.g. "kernel space" is preserved/cloned/mapped into each new virtual address space whenever a new virtual address space is created).